# zsh on macOS Montery gives syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator

Tags: zsh, macos-monterey

Regard this distilled example of the problem.

```
% echo 'echo "$((1.5*2))"' | zsh
3.
% echo 'echo "$((1.5*2))"' >x
% <x zsh
3.
% echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh
% chmod +x x
% ./x
./x: line 1: 1.5*2: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".5*2")
```

I understand this error in bash.

If I change the script to just

```
echo "$SHELL"
```

it emits /bin/zsh as expected when executed. So I have no reason to expect bash behaviour here.

Someone explain why zsh is acting like sh/bash but identifying as zsh? I'm not interested in a work around (I have several), I want to understand this. Thanks.

Comment: shbang fixes it, this is the answer. I'll leave this tab open for a couple days.

Comment: `$SHELL` is the name of your login shell, not the shell currently being executed.

Comment: To verify that you are in a zsh, I suggest that you do a `echo $ZSH_VERSION`. Since zsh does not, by default, set `SHELL`, the value of the variable can be anything from some parent process. Another good hint on what shell you are running, can be obtained by doing a `echo $0`. BTW, you don't need a #! line; you can also name the shell explicitly on invocation (`zsh SCRIPTNAME`).

Comment: IMO, the real cause of this problem a design flaw of bash: Once a bash is started, it places the variable `SHELL` into the **environment**, which means that every child process receives this variable in its environment. If bash would have made it just a normal shell variable, such confusion would never arise....

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: `zsh` is *not* executing the script; `bash` is.

---

`$SHELL` is the name of your login shell, not the currently executing shell. Unlike `bash`, which will use itself to execute a script with no shebang, `zsh` uses `/bin/sh`; from `man zshmisc`:

> If execution fails because the file is not in  executable  format,  and
> the  file  is  not  a  directory,  it  is assumed to be a shell script.
> /bin/sh is spawned to execute it.

In your case, `/bin/sh` is a shell (either `bash` or `dash`, most likely) that does not support floating-point arithmetic.